# How do i open and close something in python tkinter at the same time?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code I coded using tkinter.

```
def create_widgets(self):
    self.submit_button = Button(self, text ="Submit", command = self.popupmsg)
    self.submit_button.grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = W)



def popupmsg(self):
    popupmsg = Tk()
    popupmsg.wm_title("Test")
    self.grid()
    self.text = Text(popupmsg,text="test", width = 30, height = 10, wrap = WORD)
    self.text.grid(row = 8, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)
```

I was wondering if there is any way to open popupmsg and close create_widgets. I know about ____.destroy() but using that i can only get it to close it not close it and open a new window

Comment: There's the `destroy` method.

Comment: after destroying main window - `Tk()` - you have to use `mainloop()` again to run new main window `Tk()`.

Comment: In order to understand why what your doing isn't working, it's important to understand that `tkinter` expects there to be one and exactly one `Tk` instance. Your `popupmsg` function starts a new one, which isn't really intended behavior. Maybe you meant to use a `Toplevel` instead?

Comment: Are you multithreading? If not you will _never_ be able to do it at same time, nor should you usually need to.

Comment: Could you provide a larger section of your code or please clarify why you want to "open and close something at same time"?